# Display only Standard Posts Format on search.php results loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for a way to show only Standard posts on the search results page. I have found this code but I don't know how to insert more post formats. I need to hide customize "video" and "image".

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php if( get_post_format() == 'quote' ) : ?>
ANY OUTPUT FOR QUOTE POSTS
<?php elseif( get_post_format() == 'link' ) : ?>
ANY OUTPUT FOR LINK POSTS
<?php else : ?>
ANY OUTPUT FOR STANDARD POSTS
<?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile;
endif; //closing of the loop ?>
```

Comment: Hi, Tommaso. Can you please mark as answered previous questions before ask again? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php if( get_post_format() == 'quote' ) : ?>
ANY OUTPUT FOR QUOTE POSTS
<?php elseif( get_post_format() == 'link' ) : ?>
ANY OUTPUT FOR LINK POSTS
<?php elseif( get_post_format() == 'video' ) : ?>
ANY OUTPUT FOR VIDEO POSTS
<?php elseif( get_post_format() == 'image' ) : ?>
ANY OUTPUT FOR IMAGE POSTS
<?php else : ?>
ANY OUTPUT FOR STANDARD POSTS
<?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile;
endif; //closing of the loop ?>
```

Comment: yes but it says "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF in search.php on line 32"

Comment: Nope, sorry. Got it. 

Thank you, but it still looks kind messy. I really wanted to make a custom Search results loop but, I don't know how.